# WPF treeview expand not working in touch device

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, treeview, touchscreen

I have TreeViewItem style with a ToggleButton style implemented as below in xaml in WPF. This is not working in touch screens devices. Please help me. Not sure what is the problem.

```
 <Style x:Key="ExpanderStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton">
     <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
     <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                  <Button
                      Width="15"
                      Height="13"
                      Background="Transparent">
                      <Path
                         x:Name="ExpandPath"
                         Margin="1,1,1,1"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                         VerticalAlignment="Center"
                         Data="M 4 0 L 8 4 L 4 8 Z"
                         Fill="{DynamicResource BrushAbbGrey70}" />
                  </Button>
                  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                      <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                      <Setter TargetName="ExpandPath" Property="Data" Value="M 0 4 L 8 4 L 4 8 Z" />
                      </Trigger>
                  </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
              </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
 </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. Removing the property IsManupulatonEnabled = true from the style worked for me. Now the touch is working.